# Regex in JavaScript for first SUM/MIN/MAX/AVG found in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

What I'm trying to do is the following:

SUM(Sales) + SUM(Revenue)

or MIN(Sales) + SUM(Revenue).

What I want is the *first* calculation. So for 1), the result "SUM" will be given, and for 2) the result "MIN" will be given.

I've tried this for if statements but it's either impossible, or incredibly difficult to do that way. Could anyone guide me on potentially a RegEx way of doing this?

What I tried in if statements:

```
function hasFormula(formulaToLower) {
    // formulaToLower could equal "SUM(Sales) + SUM(Revenue)" etc
    // could also equal "SUM(Sales) + MIN(Revenue)" - this will return MIN, but it return SUM.

    if (formulaToLower.indexOf('sum') !== -1) {
         return "SUM";
    }

    if (formulaToLower.indexOf('min') !== -1) {
         return "MIN";
    }
}
```

Obviously though, this will bring out MIN first, even if it's found second, and so on...

Comment: 4K and I need to explain ... Could you add some real input and expected output ? And most importantly, what have you tried using regex ?

Comment: Can you post a example of input and output? It's hard to tell what you want to do.

Comment: Any better? No idea why this is getting close flags, it's a completely valid question.

Comment: `"MIN(Sales) + SUM(Revenue)".match(/sum|min|max|avg/i)`?

Comment: @ChrisDixon Basically you just throwed your requirements and wanted to us write a regex for you. If you want a regex, then at least show some initiative and show what you've tried using regex.

Comment: That's not what I've done at all, I've provided what I've *tried* to do, and what I feel is potentially the right thing to do and I've asked for suggestions. Like you said, I've got 4K points... I've helped many others out there, a little bit back would be nice.

Comment: @ChrisDixon and what's wrong with using a simple regex like the one above?

Comment: That works perfectly @DaggNabbit, please post as an answer and I'll accept that. That's all that was required without others being vicious towards the question.

Comment: @ChrisDixon looks like someone sniped it already, might as well go ahead and accept that one

Comment: No problem, thank you anyway. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @ChrisDixon the little bit back part, touché. My bad ...

Comment: No probs, have a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regexp that allows all the combinations you want. The matches will be returned in the correct order if you use the global modifier, or only the first one will be returned if you do not:

```
var matcher = /SUM|MIN|MAX|AVG/;

var str1 = 'SUM(Sales) + SUM(Revenue)';
var str2 = 'MIN(Sales) + SUM(Revenue)';

console.log(str1.match(matcher)[0]) // SUM
console.log(str2.match(matcher)[0]) // MIN
```

*The `[0]` part takes the first element in the array of results returned by [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).